# SENT protocol output unit is LSB. What does this mean?

Tags: transistors, sensor, symbol, protocol, units

I have read couple of datasheet of devices which uses SENT protocol. They define the output between 193 and 3896. The unit is LSB. I think that this does not mean least significant bit?

Example:
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-KP275-PB-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625b10283a015b34276c891ce0

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: because LSB is not an unit? I don't know

Answer (score 3):

It does in fact mean LSB or, alternatively, the measurement amount corresponding to 1 LSB.  The specs you're looking at are measurement ranges.  The numbers given are the highest and lowest readings you can expect.  Note that they're 12-bit readings, meaning they have a potential (positive) range of 0 to 4095.  4095 what?  Depends how it's calibrated, but to skirt that quagmire, they call it a LSB and spec those ranges accordingly.  It's kind of like using "percent of full scale" as a unit, but the fact that it's already digitized makes LSB a natural unit.

Comment: I did not understand your explanation. LSB means least significant bit or byte. Yes indeed, the 12-bit data represents a value between 0 and 4095.

Comment: Example: 2500 LSB means 2500 least siginicant bit or byte. That does not make sense..

Comment: 2500 LSB is interpreted as a numeric value of 2500 times the amount and units represented by 1 LSB.  For example, if you have a range of 0-3.3V using 12 bits, 1 LSB means 3.3v/4096, or 0.0008057V.

Answer (score 1):

At one company we've used internal terms "A/D count" or "A/D tick" for this.  The meaning was the incremental amount of physical value<sup>1</sup> which corresponds<sup>2</sup> to an increment of `1` in the digital value<sup>3</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Usually voltage or current, but could be other physical values too.
<sup>2</sup> The correspondence is usually linear.
<sup>3</sup> From 0xA2 to 0xA3, for example.

Why use arbitrary units such as LSB, A/D counts, ticks instead of using physical units of measurement?  I can see two reasons.

- The exact relationship isn't always known.
  For example, a relationship between input voltage and the A/D reading depends on the reference voltage.  The authors of the datasheet at the time of writing can't know what the reference voltage will be, and it may also vary dynamically.
- The A/D values are always integer, and it often makes sense to stay with integer calculations.  In some embedded controllers, for example, floating point math isn't practical.

I also use "epoch" as a unit of time.  A sampled system usually has a refresh rate, and one *epoch* is the refresh period.  Why not use normal units of time?  The period may be an odd-looking number when expressed in engineering units of time (how about 17.39ms).  More importantly, I may decide to change the refresh period during the project.

Sometimes I end up with `[ticks/epoch]` as a unit of measurement.  Why not.